# Adjusting rugplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is the code for a graph I am making for an article I am working on. The plot showed the predicted probabilities along a range of values in my data set. Along the x-axis is a rug plot that shows the distribution of trade share values (I provided the code and an image of the graph):

```
sitc8 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=plotdat8, aes(x = lagsitc8100, y = PredictedProbabilityMean), size = 2, color="blue") + 
  geom_ribbon(data=plotdat8, aes(x = lagsitc8100, ymin = lowersd, ymax = uppersd),
              fill = "grey50", alpha=.5) +
  ylim(c(-0.75, 1.5)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_rug(data=multi.sanctions.bust8.full@frame, aes(x=lagsitc8100), col="black", size=1.0, sides="b") + 
  xlab("SITC 8 Trade Share") + 
  ylab("Probability of Sanctions Busting") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dotted"), panel.grid.minor = 
  element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

My question is: is it possible to change the color of the lines of the rugplot of trade share in which the event I am modeling occurs? In other words, I would like to add red lines or red dots along those values of trade share when my event = 1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Neither solution worked for me. I think the problem is that the variable that changes the color from black to red is dichotomous. I want it to remain black for 0 and turn red when it is 1 while mapped to the values of trade share along the x-axis.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a solution for a black/red dichotomy based on a numeric vector of ones and zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You'd just have to add a `color` argument within an `aes()` function call within  `geom_rug()`.

Here's some code to create a dummy data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
dummy_data <- tibble(x_var = rnorm(100),
                     y_var = abs(rnorm(100)) * x_var) %>%
rownames_to_column(var = "temp_row") %>% 
mutate(color_id = if_else(as.numeric(temp_row) <= 50,
                          "Type A",
                          "Type B"))
```

And here's a ggplot call where the color for `geom_rug` is mapped to a character column named `color_id`

```
ggplot(data = dummy_data, mapping = aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_rug(mapping = aes(color = color_id), sides = "b")
```

[image]

#### Update:

Following OP's comment, here's an updated version. If it's a numeric vector of 0s and 1s, you have to tell `ggplot` to treat it as a dichotomous variable. You can do that by wrapping it in a call to `factor()` for instance.

For the color we can set that manually using `scale_color_manual()`. So the changes to the code are the following.

- `color_id` is now a vector og 0s and 1s.
- the color is now mapped to `factor(color_id)`
- the color scale is determined using `scale_color_manual`

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
dummy_data <- tibble(x_var = rnorm(100),
                     y_var = abs(rnorm(100)) * x_var) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "temp_row") %>% 
  mutate(color_id = if_else(as.numeric(temp_row) <= 50,
                            0,
                            1))

ggplot(data = dummy_data, mapping = aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_rug(mapping = aes(color = factor(color_id)), sides = "b") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  labs(color = "This takes two values")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I get what I need to do I think; I can get the labels to appear with the proper colors but the rug plot remains all black. I'll keep experimenting with the code. I think the problem is that the data that creates the line is different from the data I use to create the rug plot since the line is generated by calculating the predicted probabilities (which only includes 100 observations).

Comment: I finally got it to work! Thanks again for your help! Your code and the reply about yours were both helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible. Here's an example using iris, and a dynamic condition in the rug. You could also do two rugs, if you chose.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(aes(color = Petal.Length >3), sides = "b") 

# Second example, output not shown
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(data = subset(iris, Petal.Length > 3), color = "black", sides = "b") +
  geom_rug(data = subset(iris, Petal.Length <= 3), color = "red", sides = "b")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; after tinkering with your code and the response below, I was able to figure out how to get my graph to display properly. Subsetting the data was the way to go!